# Spring JDBC getting values returned from query

Tags: java, sql, spring, jdbc, spring-jdbc

Hi i have a query where i select values from the database and i would like to do a comparison with the selected data. I am able to create the query and pass in the parameters but i am still having some problems accessing the values returned from the query. Can someone tell me if i am on the right track, i think i wrote the last two statements incorrectly.

```
    String sql = "SELECT userName, password FROM tblusers WHERE userName = ? AND password = ? ";



    Object[] parameters = new Object[] {login.getUserName(), login.getPassword()};

    String dbUserName = (String)getJdbcTemplate().queryForObject(
            sql, parameters, String.class);

    String dbPassword = (String)getJdbcTemplate().queryForObject(
            sql, parameters, String.class);
```

Comment: Which problems are you finding?

Comment: i am not able to get values into dbUserName and dbPassword i am getting a NULL point exception error. I dont think i am pulling out the results from the query correctly is that he correct way to do it?

Comment: There are several ways to get a result using `JdbcTemplate`. If you cannot use custom objects to map the results (for example a `User` class) you can obtain results as a `Map` or a `List` of `Map`s.

Comment: its nt at all a good practice to store raw passwords in DB.

Comment: the application was updated and the passwords have been encrypted

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your query returns only one record, I suggest you to use:

[`queryForMap(String sql, Object... args)`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/simple/SimpleJdbcTemplate.html#queryForMap%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29)

Take a look at javadoc.

For your specific problem this should work:

```
Map<String,Object> results = 
        getJdbcTemplate().queryForMap(
            "SELECT userName, password FROM tblusers WHERE userName = ? AND password = ?"
            , login.getUserName()
            , login.getPassword());

String dbUserName = (String)results.get("userName");
String dbPassword = (String)results.get("password");
```

Comment: with this i am getting an error : org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.EmptyResultDataAccessException: Incorrect result size: expected 1, actual 0

Comment: well actually occur because of no records can you tell me whats the best way to handle this type of error

Comment: the best way to handle an empty result set is to catch the `org.springframework.dao.EmptyResultDataAccessException`

Answer (score 2):

Your query would return two strings, if that is what you intend then you should convert your results into an object, OR just query for username and password one at at time. Here is how you can use a row-mapper to get both username and password at the same time.

```
    public class CustomRowMapper implements RowMapper {

        public Object mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
            User user = new User();
            user.setPassword(rs.getString("password");
            user.setUserName(rs.getString("userName"); 
            return user;  
        }
    }


    String sql = "SELECT userName, password FROM tblusers WHERE userName = ? AND password =        ? ";

    Object[] parameters = new Object[] {login.getUserName(), login.getPassword()};

    User u = (User) getJdbcTemplate().queryForObject(sql, parameters, new CustomRowMapper());
```

Otherwise ...

```
String sql = "SELECT userName FROM tblusers WHERE userName = ? AND password = ? ";

String userName = getJdbcTemplate().queryForString(sql, parameters);

String passwordSql = String sql = "SELECT password FROM tblusers WHERE userName = ? AND password = ? ";

String password= getJdbcTemplate().queryForString(sql, parameters);
```

Comment: +1 for showing both the RowMapper solution, that's what I would steer him towards.